# Cannot Find RequestPath Module isexe

Tags: reactjs, npm, bamboo

I am running `npm run test:CI` (jest-html-reporter) in Bamboo CI but this error occurred:

```
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:361
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\...\node_modules\isexe\index.js'. 
Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

path: '...node_modules\\isexe\\package.json',
requestPath: 'isexe'
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

The main in my `package.json` is set to 'dist/index.js'

What is this error and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try to clean the cache:

```
npm cache clean
```

If it doesn't work try:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Also, I cannot see your folder structure, but I think the route is: './dist/index.js', not 'dist/index.js'.

Answer (score 1):

Just cleaning the cache didn't work for me but removing the modules directory and the lock file did.

##### Steps

1. Delete `package-lock.json`.
2. Delete `node_modules` directory.
3. Run `npm-install`